# Registering file associations in MFC doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mfc

This problem I am having is very easy to reproduce. Create a basic MFC MDI application with file extension as .xyz using Visual Studio 2010. The application default code readily registers the file associations via calls:

```
 // Enable DDE Execute open
 EnableShellOpen();
 RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);
```

The problem is that inside RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE), the call below fails:

```
if (!_AfxSetRegKey(strFileTypeId, strFileTypeName))
   continue;       // just skip it
```

The file is obviously not being registered and it doesn't adopt the application assigned file icon. All I want is when I double click the registered file type (in this case .xyz) it should open in the application but it doesn't. What is possibly missing..how to make this work?

Comment: Don't know about that! My application is suppose to run on any Windows 7 machine so I would prefer a universal solution.

Comment: Registering an application extension needs admin privileges. Does it work if you run your application as admin ?

Comment: I do have admin privileges on PC so I believe the application is running as admin.

Comment: Even if your user has admin privileges your program won't have those privileges unless the manifest specifically asks for them. You'll probably still need to click a box allowing the program to run with those privileges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft has changed their concept of registering an extension over the years. Starting with Vista, it's expected that the extension will be registered at installation time with a Setup application which will have Admin privileges. The registry keys necessary to map an extension to an application are now in a protected area of the registry. What you're asking for is no longer possible.

Comment: You might want to mention UAC elevation instead of admin privileges.  Being an admin is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You need administrator privileges to accomplish this. Usually, you should let your installer register your files. However, it can be done if you explicitly elevate (and re-run) your process before your file types are registered:

```
// In your InitInstance, do the following:
OSVERSIONINFOEX osvi;
osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof OSVERSIONINFOEX;
GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&osvi);

if (osvi.dwMajorVersion >= 6) // XP or Vista/elevated?
{
    TCHAR exePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, exePath, MAX_PATH);
    ShellExecute(NULL, _T("runas"), exePath, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: This starts a new instance of my application which is undesirable. I want to register the files with same instance.

Answer (score 1):

As  Parapura Rajkumar mentioned, if you put this code in your init instance:

```
 // Enable DDE Execute open
 EnableShellOpen();
 RegisterShellFileTypes(TRUE);
```

The application should run at least one time as admin (right click and run as administrator) to register file types in windows registry.